# Upstart script doesn't start

Tags: scripts, upstart, init, pure-ftpd

Ubuntu 10.04

I have created this upstart script (*/etc/init/pure-ftpd.conf*):

```
# pure-ftpd - FTP server

description "Pure-FTPd server"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel S

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
pid file /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid
console output

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

exec /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd --maxclientsnumber 2 --maxclientsperip 10 --prohibitdotfileswrite --prohibitdotfilesread --noanonymous --chrooteveryone --dontresolve --nochmod --pidfile /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid
```

But...

```
# start pure-ftpd
start: Unknown job: pure-ftpd
```

and

```
# service pure-ftpd start
start: Unknown job: pure-ftpd
```

What's the problem? 
Is it necessary to do something more?
Is it necessary to create one script in /etc/init.d too?

Comment: I met same trouble. Please try initctl command at console.
To enter console session, press Ctrl + ALT + F1 and login. (I can't understand why, but I successed this way)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It usually means you have an error in the `.conf` file - for instance I'm not sure the `pid` stanza is supported in 10.04, `stop` can't be used in the script etc.

I'd try starting the file from scratch (with only `start`, `stop` etc), and then slowly building it up by adding more and more lines and testing it via `start pure-ftpd`.

For example:

```
# cat pure-ftpd.conf 
start on filesystem
stop on runlevel S

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

# start pure-ftpd
pure-ftpd start/running

# cat pure-ftpd.conf 
start on filesystem
stop on runlevel S

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
pid file /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid

# start pure-ftpd
start: Unknown job: pure-ftpd
```

Comment: The information in the wiki is very outdated (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/).
By other side, the upstart version in Lucid is 0.6.5-8 and the pid file should be supported: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas?highlight=%28%28CategoryDoc%29%29#pid

Comment: AFAIK the `pid` stanza have been removed since the version `0.5.0  2008-08-12  "One of those deaf-mutes"`. Don't use it.

Comment: Someone knows where is the updated documentation?

Answer (score 46):

You can also run `init-checkconf` to check syntax

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/job.conf
File /etc/init/job.conf: syntax ok
```

Comment: The command does not exist in 10.04, but it does exist in 12.04.

Comment: But it does not work on on a headless Ubuntu 12.04 server (yet). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/881885

Comment: Found the issue straightaway! - Should be built into the `start` command so it gives you a more informative error message...

Answer (score 26):

First, you can check that your job is actually known to upstart:

```
sudo initctl list | grep your_job_name
```

...where `your_job_name` is the name of your upstart script minus the `.conf` extension.

If it's not found, you can try reloading the configuration and then re-checking:

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration

# re-check
sudo initctl list | grep your_job_name
```

Then try again to start your job:

```
sudo start your_job_name
```

If you weren't getting any logging in `/var/log/daemon.log` or `/var/log/syslog` before, you might have some now.

Comment: And what if this shows that the job is not known to upstart, even though the syntax is correct and it resides in /etc/init?

Comment: Did you try "sudo initctl reload-configuration" as suggested? Did you check permissions, logs, docs?

Comment: I did, and did again after reading your comment. Even made sure that the user was a system-user (useradd -r). Perhaps there may be something else wrong -unrelated to upstart - so I posted an issue to the developers of the service I'm trying to start (it is shiny-server I'm trying to start on boot).

Comment: And it was permissions after all! even though everything looked peachy when listing the dir, only after a chmod 644 did initctl pick up the script. Thanks again.

Comment: ubuntu is a pain, i don't remember having to run all these commands in rhel just update the conf file and start. Why is reload-configuration necessary? It worked though thanks.

Comment: @radtek For performance,  daemons commonly don't re-read configuration files unless you explicitly tell them to. PostgreSQL, Nginx and Apache are examples of services like this. In the example of Upstart-based init, the official docs have this note: "This command is generally not necessary since init(8) watches its configuration directories with inotify(7) and  automatically reloads in cases of changes."   In this case, automatic reloading failed due to bad permissions.

Comment: Remember, the your_job_name is without the .conf ending of the file. Took me an hour to find out.

Answer (score 6):

The most relevant reference for job file syntax will be available when you run the command:

```
man 5 init
```

on your system. For Ubuntu 10.04, as you found in the previous answer, the pid file syntax is incorrect.

Any time you get that 'unknown job" error back, its a good idea to check the logs (pre 11.04, /var/log/daemon.log, 11.04 and greater everything goes in /var/log/syslog)

You may see an error like this:

```
init: /etc/init/test.conf:2: Unknown stanza
```

Answer (score 3):

Anyway I'am here because i had the same problem, but my syntax was 100% correct.

After some debugging I discovered another issue that can cause this *"Unknown job"* error:

**upstarts** uses **inotify** to monitor .conf file changes and auto install jobs, this is very cool *(for this you don't need something like update.rc with upstart!)* but can be not perfect if you (like me in that case) use some FTP/SCP GUI program to upload and edit configurations on remote servers, the job can be silently uninstalled by upstart when you edit file in that manner.

to fix simply do that *(that saved me)*

```
touch /etc/init/*
```

it will generate inotify events to refresh all upstart confs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my Ubuntu 14.04 Docker containers. As it turns out, the Ubuntu 14.04 image (if not others) for Docker does not support Upstart in the same way that a full virtual machine would.

To answer this question, why the service does not start, it is because initctl is not an actual Upstart program: it is mapped to /bin/true.

To verify run the following on a Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container vs. Vagrant, and vs. a DigitalOcean droplet

```
$ ls -al /sbin/initctl
```

You'll see initctl is not the same in Docker vs. the others.

A link that may further your understanding.. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1024

Comment: Ran into the same problem with docker: in short and to summarize, docker only runs one process at a time so it cannot run upstart and something else.
To make sure to restart the service if/when it dies, i ended up using supervisord.
PS: you should not run multiple services in a container: the whole point of using containers is to build micro services, so build the pieces in separate containers and bring them together with Docker-Compose

Comment: I just ran into this article and that gives very good advice about how to separate concerns:
http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/
which is probably the even better strategy to use than to use supervisor