# bash command doesn't run in upstart

Tags: server, bash, upstart, django

I'm setting up a django project following [H. Percival's TDD](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch08.html#_using_upstart_to_make_sure_gunicorn_starts_on_boot). 
By the end of the chapter I setup an Upstart process to start the server with Gunicorn using Nginx as well.

My upstart file `/etc/init/gunicorn-superlists-staging.conf` looks like this:

```
description "Gunicorn server for superlists-staging"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid diego
chdir /home/diego/sites/superlists-staging/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
  --bind unix:/tmp/superlists-staging.socket \
  superlists.wsgi:application
```

And running it with `sudo start` I get the error:

```
start: Unknown job: gunicorn-superlists_staging
```

What confuses me is that I can run the last command fine from the server,

```
../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
    --bind unix:/tmp/superlists_staging.socket \
    superlists.wsgi:application
```

and this is where the error is.

The way to identify the error follows [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30796/upstart-script-doesnt-start) post.  That is, I comment all the instructions and uncomment one at a time until it breaks in the last one.

My server is in AWS.  What else should I provide for fixing this?

Comment: "... which is where the error is." How did you know that? Is there more to the error message than you have shown here?

Comment: I edited the question, to include my fix.  I also found errors with `init-checkconf` but don't have the output at the moment.

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't find a single example in the Upstart cookbook where `\ ` is used to continue the command over the next line. Try putting the entire command on one line.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it.  Another possibility is having changed the server's name when being referenced in the upstart process.  That is, keeping it at `superlists-staging` instead of the whole `ec2-ip-region-.compute.amazonaws.com`.  Could this have something to do?

Comment: Dunno. Did you make a typo somewhere? The error says `gunicorn-superlists_staging` with a `_`, but the file name is `gunicorn-superlists-staging.conf`.

Comment: You hit the nail.  It wasn't a typo, but it was a bad choice of character.  Bash does recognize `_` but apparently not Upstart for some reason.  Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: @Diego, was this fixed by muru's last comment?