# Upstart logs don't exist?

Tags: 14.04, upstart, logging, docker

I'm on 14.04 and my init system is upstart. I'm trying to grab some logs from an application (Docker daemon). Debugging is switched on, it runs via upstart, but I have no directory `/var/log/upstart` (and therefore no `/var/log/upstart/docker.log` which is where it's meant to log to).

Am I missing something obvious? Numerous google searches just turn up "it's in `/var/log/upstart`" but I can't find any threads for cases where that directory doesn't exist!

Comment: Check this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/30796/upstart-script-doesnt-start